# Unable to connect Powershell to AzureSQL database

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-active-directory, ssms

I am writing a Powershell script that should connect and query the database (that is hosted in Azure). I am able to connect without a problem to SSMS using my AzureAD ID. However, I am unable to do the same in Powershell. I am using this pattern for my connection string:

```
"Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Password;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUser@myDomain;PWD=myPassword;"
```

Just to be clear, the connection string works perfectly fine and the DB admin told me that I have all the needed permissions. What is the possible cause for this? I tried both Invoke-SqlCMD and ADO.net. Please help!!

Comment: Have you installed the [prerequisite ADAL.DLL drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure#configure-your-client-computers)? SSMS installs the 32-bit version and you may be running in a 64-bit PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that is the case. Although I did not install these, it should not be a problem since I can connect to other servers. My problem is with one specific server. The solution I am hoping for should be around configuring a server to allow powershell connections so that I can tell the DB administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code I ran as a test and it worked fine.

```
$server = "tcp:thesqlservername.database.windows.net,1433"
$database = "testdb"
$adminName = "testuser01@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com"
$adminPassword = "TestPassword"
$connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User ID=$adminName;Password=$adminPassword;authentication=Active Directory Password;"
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "dsPersonData"
$q = @"
SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] 
"@
$da = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($q, $connection)
$da.Fill($ds)
$dtPerson = $ds.Tables[0]
```

I created a demo azure sql db, set the test user as "active directory admin" on the sql server in azure, and installed smss (management studio) on my desktop to test.

what error are you getting?

Comment: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At line:46 char:1
+ $da.Fill($ds)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException

Comment: somewhere in there, after $connection line, can you type $connection.open() and see if you get any output from the open() ?

Comment: if you get exception calling open with "0" arguments, then it basically means it doesn't like your credentials, either username or password. possibly you have some characters in your password that is causing issues with the parsing in powershell? in the connection string, of the $adminPassword try to wrap it in ``" (only one reverse tick in front of the ", stackoverflow is escaping my string when I put only 1 of the ticks. in powershell the escape character is `.

Comment: Thanks. This, probably, has to do with how the server is set up. I also created a demo Azure SQL DB and I can connect.